# Minimum cost to convert a string to other

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given 2 strings A and B of the same length N. A contains '0', '1', and '?'; B contains only '0' and '1'. We need to find minimum cost of transforming A into B by performing sequence of allowed operations with string A.

Following operations are allowed:

1. Change '0' to '1' with cost x
2. Change '1' to '0' with cost y
3. Change '?' to either '0' or '1' with cost z
4. Swap two adjacent characters with cost t.

**We need to find minimum cost.**

**Example** : Let N=6 , x=1 , y=1000 , z=1 , t=1 , A=01??00 and B=001010 then answer is 4.

How to solve this problem using dynamic programming ? What can be recurrence for it ? Please help

Comment: What the expected time complexity(or what the constraints are)?

Comment: @kraskevich 1 ≤ N ≤ 2000 and 1 ≤ x, y, z, t ≤ 1000 . Also z ≤ min(x, y) so O(N^2) will work

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a few observation:

1. If we match all ones in both strings, zeros will get matched automatically.
2. The order of operations does not matter. That is, we can assume that we first make all changes(0 to 1, 1 to 0, or ? to something) and after that we perform all swaps.
3. Let's assume that the positions of 1's in the first string a `(p_1, p_2, ..., p_n)` and in the second string they are `(q_1, q_2, ..., q_n)`. Then we minimize the cost of swaps if we match `p` to `q` in sorted order.
4. Let's take a look at positions `i` and `i + 1`. Let's define `balance[i]` as the difference of number of ones in `a` and `b` in the prefix of length `i + 1`. Then exactly `balance[i]` swaps will touch these two elements. This claim is implied by step 3.
5. All this observations lead to the following dynamic programming solution: the state is `(prefix length, current balance)`. The value is the smallest cost to process the prefix of the given length so that the balance is equal to a specified value. There are `O(N ^ 2)` states. How to make transitions? We can just try to put everything to the current position of `a` and compute the cost appropriately.
6. The answer is `f(N, 0)`.

Here is some code:

```
public class Task {

    final int INF = 1_000_000_000;

    int cost01;
    int cost10;
    int costUnknown;
    int costSwap;

    int getDeltaBalance(int c1, int c2) {
        return c1 - c2;
    }

    int getCost(char start, int want) {
        if (start == '?')
            return costUnknown;
        if (start - '0' == want)
            return 0;
        if (start == '1')
            return cost10;
        return cost01;
    }

    public void solve(Scanner in, PrintWriter out) throws IOException {
        int n = in.nextInt();
        cost01 = in.nextInt();
        cost10 = in.nextInt();
        costUnknown = in.nextInt();
        costSwap = in.nextInt();
        String a = in.next();
        String b = in.next();
        int[][] dp = new int[n + 1][2 * n + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            Arrays.fill(dp[i], INF);
        }
        dp[0][n] = 0;
        for (int pos = 0; pos < n; pos++) {
            for (int balance = -n; balance <= n; balance++) {
                for (int curNumber = 0; curNumber <= 1; curNumber++) {
                    int newBalance = balance + getDeltaBalance(curNumber, b.charAt(pos) - '0');
                    if (newBalance < -n || newBalance > n)
                        continue;
                    int newCost = dp[pos][balance + n] + costSwap * Math.abs(balance)
                            + getCost(a.charAt(pos), curNumber);
                    dp[pos + 1][newBalance + n] = Math.min(dp[pos + 1][newBalance + n], newCost);
                }
            }
        }
        out.println(dp[n][n]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughly the ruby code would be this. It will pass the few online challenges of ruby

```
def abc
u=gets.to_i
val = []
w=[]
for i in (1..u)
k=i+1
k3=i+2
costi = 0
costk = 0
costk3=0
n, x, y, z, t= [gets.split.map(&:to_i)].first
q = [x,y].min
if (1..1000).include?(x) and (1..1000).include?(y) and (1..q).include?(z)  and (1..1000).include?(t)
a=[gets.chomp.split(//)].first
a.keep_if{|v| v == "0"|| v == "1" || v == "?"}
a.keep_if{a.length == n}
c=a.clone
d=a.clone
b=[gets.chomp.split(//)].first
b.keep_if{|v| v == "0"|| v == "1"}
b.keep_if{b.length == a.length}
if b.length!=a.length
break
end 
val.push(n)
end
end_val = val.sort
count = (val.count*0.3).to_i
if (1..2000).include?(val.inject(0,:+)) &&    end_val.first(count).inject(0,:+)<=25
for p in (0..2)
if p == 0
m=a.length
for l in (0..m-1)
if a[l] != b[l]
   if a[l] == "0" 
     a[l] = "1"
     costi =  costi + x
  elsif a[l] == "1"
       a[l] = "0"
       costi = costi + y
  elsif a[l] == "?"
        a[l] = b[l]
        costi = costi + z
 end
end
end
elsif p ==1
m=a.length
$m =m
$i=0
while $i < $m do
if c[$i] != b[$i]
if c[$i] == b[$i+1] && c[$i+1] == b[$i]     
    c[$i] = b[$i]
    c[$i+1] = b[$i+1] 
    costk =costk + t
    $i +=1
elsif c[$i] == b[$i+1]
       e1 = c[$i+1] 

       c[$i+1] = c[$i]

       c[$i]=e1           
         costk =  costk + t
        if c[$i] == "?"
    c[$i] = b[$i]
    costk =  costk + z
    elsif c[$i] == "0"
  c[$i] = b[$i]
    costk =  costk + x
elsif c[$i] == "1"
c[$i] = b[$i]
    costk =  costk + y            
end
elsif c[$i+1] == b[$i]
     e2 = c[$i]  

 c[$i] = c[$i+i]

 c[$i+1]=e2
         costk =  costk + t
 if c[$i+1] == "?"
   c[$i+1] = b[$i+1]
    costk =  costk + z
 elsif c[$i+1] == "0"
  c[$i+1] = b[$i+1]
    costk =  costk + x
 elsif c[$i+1] == "1"
 c[$i+1] = b[$i+1]
    costk =  costk + y            
 end        
  elsif c[$i] == "?"
     c[$i] = b[$i]
    costk =  costk + z
 elsif c[$i] == "0"
  c[$i] = b[$i]
    costk =  costk + x
 elsif c[$i] == "1"
 c[$i] = b[$i]
    costk =  costk + y            
end
end
$i +=1
end
elsif p==2
m=a.length
$m =m
$i=$m-1
while $i >=0 do
if d[$i] != b[$i]
if d[$i] == b[$i-1] && d[$i-1] == b[$i]     
    d[$i] = b[$i]
    d[$i-1] = b[$i-1] 
    costk3 =costk3 + t
    $i -=1
    elsif d[$i-1] == b[$i]
        e4 = d[$i] 
        d[$i] = d[$i-i]
     d[$i-1]=e4
         costk3 =  costk3 + t  
       if d[$i-1] == "?"
    d[$i-1] = b[$i-1]
    costk3 =  costk3 + z
    elsif d[$i-1] == "0"
    d[$i-1] = b[$i-1]
    costk3 =  costk3 + x
    elsif d[$i-1] == "1"
    d[$i-1] = b[$i-1]
    costk3 =  costk3 + y            
    end 
    elsif d[$i] == "?"
    d[$i] = b[$i]
    costk3 =  costk3 + z
    elsif d[$i] == "0"
    d[$i] = b[$i]
    costk3 =  costk3 + x
    elsif d[$i] == "1"
    d[$i] = b[$i]
    costk3 =  costk3 + y            
    end
    end
    $i -=1
    end
    end
    end
    end
    v =[ costi, costk,costk3].min
    w.push(v)
    end
    puts w
    return w
    end
    abc
```